# Change Consecutive Row value

Tags: sql, subquery

I am trying to change value of Consecutive AA to first AA as AA1 and second one as AA2, if only one AA then it should be as AA1, its possible to change all AA to AA1 and then search for 2nd consecutive AA1 to change it AA2 example:

[image]

Comment: Please specify which DBMS?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need an ordering column to define consecutive.  Your sample data suggests that `name` can be used for this purpose, although that would be unorthodox.

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  In this case, you can use the difference of row numbers to define adjacent rows with the same department.  Then, the rest is conditional logic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by dept) > 1
             then concat(dept, row_number() over (partition by dept, seqnum - seqnum_2)
             else dept
        end)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by name) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by dept order by name) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use cursor with two variable one for current and one for previous and then we can check it inside the loop and update the table:

```
Declare db_cursor for Select * from t;
Open db_cursor;
Declare @name varchar(5); Declare @prevName varchar(5);
Declare @dept varchar(5); Declare @preDept varchar(5);
Fetch from db_cursor into @name, @dept;
Set @prevName = @name; Set @prevDept = @dept;
Fetch from db_cursor into @name, @dept;
While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
IF(@dept=@prevDept)
BEGIN

    Update t set Dept='AA2' where Dept=@dept

END
Set @prevName = @name; Set @prevDept = @dept;
Fetch from db_cursor into @name, @dept;
END
```